# choosing pair of same socks from black box - 7 red, 5 blue 1 green

Tags: independence

I dont know how to solve this.

Problem: black box has socks,i need to take 2 socks of the same color.
what is the max number of socks i have to take for this if the box has 7 red, 5 blue and 1 green sock?

my thought process:

- if i take 1 available green sock, i have to repeat and take another 2 from the rest( 7+5). So this is 1 green + 1/12 * 1/11.
- if i take 1 red, then i have to select from the rest which is 1/12 * 1/11

could you assist with this?

Comment: Write a tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of probabilities, it's a problem of combinations, so you shouldn't be thinking in terms of fractions.

Instead, think about what the *worst* case scenario is - how many socks can you take from the drawer while still not having two of the same colour?

Answer (score 0):

The probabilities are on a draw tree for the first draw

pred=7/13, pblue=5/13 and pgreen=1/13

They add up to one.

For the second draw pgreen=0 if we already draw the green sock. In all other cases pgreen=1/12 because one sock is already removed. For this event, the probability is for the path {1,0,1} p=7/156 and {0,1,1}=5/156. For {2,0,0}: p=42/156, {1,1,0}=35/156, {0,2,0}: p=20/156, where {red,blue,green} sock is drawn.

The sock is drawn and not done back into the box.

First draw step:
{0,0,0} ->{1,0,0}
->{0,1,0}
->{0,0,1}
Second draw step:
{1,0,0}->{2,0,0}
{1,1,0}
{1,0,1}
{0,1,0}->{1,1,0}
{0,2,0}
{0,1,1}
{0,0,1}->{1,0,1}
{0,1,1}
{0,0,2}
and so one.

As reference have a look at [Urn_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem) and [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Since there is only one green sock the expectation to get a green sock depends on the number of draws n and the probability to get the green sock pgreen=1/13: n/13.
So after 13 draws You are sure to get the green sock. And for each such draw the probability of not drawing the green sock is n*12/169, so after 13 draws that probability is 12/13. And so on.

This is a probability problem and a distribution problem. Have a look at [Combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) for what combinatorics is about in Mathematics.